# How to store custom data inside of svg-objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I plan to have some (a lot of) objects inside of svg-object that will be generated using JavaScript.

User will do different activities with them: click, mouse-over, mouse-out. Once any event is occurred some data that are object specific are required to be displayed.

**Question:** how to get data about object? For example, user clicked on rectangle that represents car of "Make A" (there are few rectangles, each of them represents a separate make). How can I determine a make? Is there any way to associate 'external data' with svg-objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not store things within the [jquery.data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) object?

Comment: Add more details.

Answer (score 14):

The [Event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event) object you get in the click/mouseover/etc-handler has a property called `target` that is the element (technically any EventTarget, but in this case it's the element) that the event was first dispatched to.

One way to store custom data is to use namespaced attributes. The reason why you should namespace your attributes is that they may clash with existing or future svg attributes.

Here's an example:

```
var rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
rect.setAttributeNS("http://www.example.com/yourcustomnamespace", "data", "whatever-data-you-want-here");
rect.addEventListener("click", myclickhandler, false);
...

function myclickhandler(evt)
{
  var target = evt.target;
  // specialcase for use elements
  if (target.correspondingUseElement)
    target = target.correspondingUseElement;
  alert(target);
  alert(target.getAttributeNS("http://www.example.com/yourcustomnamespace", "data"))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can store a reference to a SVG object created in a simple javascript variable. So, when you create a shape, you can do this:

```
myRect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
```

Now you have the reference to a shape of the SVG object. But if you want to make them interactive, you just have to add attributes to the object like this.

```
myRect.setAttribute("onclick", "jsFunc()");
```

where jsFunc() is a previously defined function. Also, to make things easier, you can set the events this way:

```
myRect.onclick = function(){jsFunct(this, otherArg);}
```

Now You can not only have the reference to the variable, but to pass the variable itself to the function jsFunc using such alternative through the use of the pointer this.

If you have to create a lot of Rectangles, you can store them all in a single Array, so you are able to access each element using an index:

```
myRect = new Array();
for(i = 1; i <= numMakes; i = i + 1){
    myRect[i] = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
}
```

Remember, to get a property or attribute of your object, you can use the function getAttribute, like this:

```
fillColor = myRect.getAttribute("fill");
x = myRect.getAttribute("x");
```

and so on.

You could create a new variable type object, and establish that one member is the svg shape, and the rest of members are your customized data fields.

```
var myRect = new Object();
myRect.shape = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
myRect.customField = myValue;
```

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand how to store custom data inside of rect object..? Could you clarify? Thanks.

Comment: You could create a new variable type object, and establish that one member is the svg shape, and the rest of members are your customized data fields.

Comment: Ok, but how can I determine that parent-object using a shape? Do you propose to go through array of parent-objects and detect which of them contains my shape?

Comment: this fails to answer the question, and vaguely addresses its own solution

Answer (score 2):

While generally not safe to assume that it's possible to extend native objects with js expando properties, in all browser SVG implementations, it's safe to store data on SVG DOM nodes using regular expando properties, e.g.

```
node.myCustomData = "foo"
```

Note that this doesn't work in Batik.

You can read these threads for more information:

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/svg-developers/message/64659

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/svg-developers/message/63002

Answer (score 1):

You can store your custom data inside SVG by using custom tags or attributes - just make sure you use your own namespace:

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/extend.html#ForeignNamespaces

Answer (score 0):

I see one solution myself: during populating svg-object with items I **can generate 'id'** for each item in way like this: "makeA", "makeB", "car_id_10", "bike_id_20", ... etc. And in the event listener I will get event target id, go into a special array that will describe objects...

Is it a good idea? Not sure...

Comment: Can you tell how i can use this approach if im creating an svg from Adobe Illustrator?

Answer (score 0):

DOM Elements may have arbitrary objects stored in attributes, not just strings as you might enter in "normal" html code.

```
someSVGElement.setAttribute("myApp.car.model", Global.Car.Models.mercedes");
```

Additionally, as of jquery 3, jquery supports its .data(...) method (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) on svg elements