# Play a sound on hover state

Tags: javascript, html, audio, hover

I'm trying to create a banner that would somehow look like a soundwave but behave like a piano keyboard. I'd like each key of this keyboard to play a short **unique** sound (.ogg or .mp3 samples) on **hover** state.

I know how to implement this using Flash but I'd like to stick to HTML/JS for this project and I'm having trouble actually getting it done.

The "keyboard" would look like this (**SVG**) :

[image: Keyboard]

Could you give me a few hints on how to implement this?

I'm thinking `<svg>`, `<canvas>`, or image maps could be good options.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Something like - http://www.html5piano.com/???

Comment: Something like that, yes. Except I want to achieve something simpler, I don't need the sequencer or the chord system.

Comment: I would utilize a SVG image and set up JavaScript handlers, which plays the sound (remember to pre-load the sound files).

Comment: Do you have a demo of what you have right now? And, can you use jQuery?

Comment: Not really. In a nutshell, imagine hovering your mouse over each pink rectangle, I'd like to play a different sound samples (basically, a note) for each rectangle. The project relies on jQuery for other purposes, so it is definitely an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** You can try something like this instead:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/xmXFf/

jQuery:

```
$("#layer1 rect").each(function(i) {
    $("#playme").clone().attr({
        "id": "playme-" + i,
        "src": B64Notes[i]
    }).appendTo($("#playme").parent());
    $(this).data("audio", i);
});
$("#layer1 rect").hover(function() {
    var playmeNum = $("#playme-" + $(this).data("audio"));
    playmeNum.attr("src", playmeNum[0].src)[0].play();
    // Reset the src to stop and restart so you can mouseover multiple times before the audio is finished
    $(this).css("fill", "red");
}, function() {
    $(this).css("fill", "#d91e63");
});​
```

I realize that you want to avoid duplication but there's no way to have multiple notes playing at the same time otherwise.

The svg is directly in the page to make the code simpler and because it would load from another domain preventing the jQuery from accessing and modifying it. To access the svg document when it's embedded from an external source, please see: http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/get-embedded-svg-document-script.html

Comment: I thought of something like this, but I need to play a different sound for each key. Your script is interesting though, do you think it could be applied to an SVG-based system? The real trick is to assign a unique sound sample to each key without duplicating `<audio>` objects.

Comment: If you apply a [data attribute to each svg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012687/how-to-store-custom-data-inside-of-svg-objects) shape then get the audio file matching it, it could work. Do you have a sample svg file?

Comment: Yes, here you go : https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxZ05BW0EtgHOG5hRGNrSjFvRWM/edit. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @morgi Done, took a long time, but it was fun :D

Comment: The Dropbox file was messed up again, I fixed it.

Comment: No problem. The only thing is, if you had a lot of elements or a different situation, the better way to do the audio elements would probably be to build a single string and then insert them all at once. Or, in this case, to delete the original, cloned, audio element.

Comment: If the simultaneity (the notes playing at the same time) was not required, would it be possible to do this without cloning the `audio` object? I mean, do you think a single `audio` object (to which we would just change the `src` attribute according to the `rect`) could be an option?

Comment: Yes, definitely. Use this code: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/6DCeE/ But then the audio cuts off as soon as you hover on another element.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I was thinking of generating very short sounds, that way I won't have to worry about the simultaneity problem. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 3):

How about assigning each key an id and using html5 `<audio>`?
Then using jQuery change the src attribute of audio tag?

```
$('#a').hover(function(){
    $('#oggfile').attr("src","a.ogg");
    $('#mpegfile').attr("src","a.mp3");
});

$('#c').hover(function(){
    $('#oggfile').attr("src","a.ogg");
    $('#mpegfile').attr("src","a.mp3");
});

$('#c').hover(function(){
    $('#oggfile').attr("src","c.ogg");
    $('#mpegfile').attr("src","c.mp3");
});
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wPGSv/

Comment: I would like to avoid duplication and `<div>`-based solutions (especially since I already have an SVG shape ready to be implemented).

Comment: You can definetly do this with less code, probably someone can assist you with that, but this is the best I can do. Image mapping?